# How to get a specific frame in a web page and retrieve its content

Tags: python, html, browser, selenium, webautomation

I wanted to access the translation results of the following url

> [http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=en&tl=ar&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.saltycrane.com%2Fblog%2F2008%2F10%2Fhow-escape-percent-encode-url-python%2F](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=en&tl=ar&u=http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/10/how-escape-percent-encode-url-python/)

the translation is displayed in the bottom  content frame out of the two frames. I am interested in retrieving only the bottom content frame to get the translations

selenium for python allows us to fetch page contents via web automation:

```
browser.get('http://translate.google.com/#en/ar/'+hurl)
```

The required frame is an iframe :

```
<div id="contentframe" style="top:160px"><iframe   src="/translate_p?hl=en&am... name=c frameborder="0" style="height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px;"></div></iframe>
```

but how to get the bottom content frame element to retrieve the translations using web automation?

Came to know that PyQuery also allows us to browse the contents using the JQuery formalism

**Update:**

An answer mentioned that Selenium provides a method where you can do that.

```
frame = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
browser.switch_to_frame(frame)
# get page source
browser.page_source
```

but it does not work in the above example. It returns an empty page .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `driver.switchTo.frame(1);` here, the digit 1 inside frame() is the index of frames present in the webpage. as your requirement is to switch to second frame and the index starts with 0, you should use `driver.switchTo.frame(1);`

But the above code is in Java. In Python, you can use the below line.

```
driver.switch_to_frame(1);
```

**UPDATE**

```
 driver.get("http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=en&tl=ar&u=http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/10/how-escape-percent-encode-url-python/");
 driver.switchTo().frame(0);
 System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[3]/h1/span/a")).getText());
```

**Output:** SaltyCrane ???????

I have just tried to print the title name SaltCrane that is present inside the iframe.
It worked for me except for the ? symbols after the SaltCrane. As it was arabic, it was unable to decode the same.

The above code is in Java. Same logic should also work in Python.

Comment: its showing an error:NoSuchFrameException: Message: u'Unable to locate frame: 1' ; Stacktrace: Method FirefoxDriver.prototype.switchToFrame threw an error in file:///c:/users/.../extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js 
>

Comment: Try giving `driver.switch_to_frame(0);` it is the only frame present in the webpage. I was able to switch to the frame and click the SaltyCrane header link.

Comment: did you get the translated page?

Comment: Yes. it was a translated page. I have updated the above answer. kindly check the same and let me know if you are still facing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium provides a method where you can do that.

```
frame = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
browser.switch_to_frame(frame)
# get page source
browser.page_source
```

Comment: how to get the specific iframe source with name="c" as showed in the question?