# Selenium WebDriver -- Can't get into an iframe with dynamic ID

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium, I try to reach an element inside an iframe.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<iframe id="DWT54_content_ifr" src='javascript:""' frameborder="0" 
allowtransparency="true" title="Texte richeFaites ALT-F10 pour accéder à la 
barre d'outils. Faites ALT-0 pour accéder à l'aide" style="width: 100%; 
height: 0px; display: block;">

<body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " 
onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('DWT54_content').onLoad.dispatch();" 
contenteditable="true" dir="LTR" style="font-family: &quot;times new 
roman&quot;, &quot;new york&quot;, times, serif; font-size: 14pt; color: 
rgb(0, 0, 0);"><div><br></div></body></iframe>
```

Here is my Python code to get into the iframe:

```
time.sleep(3)
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_id("DWT54_content_ifr"))

I also tried these codes:
driver.switch_to_frame("DWT54_content_ifr")

and

driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='DWT54_content_ifr']"))
```

But each time I get the same error: "Unable to locate element".

**UPDATE:**

I managed to get into the iframe using this line of code:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(3)
```

But this is not very convenient as I have to count manually the number of iframe in the page...

Any help, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this selector `iframe[id$='_content_ifr']`, incase of DWT54 is randomly generated everytime. Put wait for the element visibility, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a specific frame in a web page and retrieve its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785920/how-to-get-a-specific-frame-in-a-web-page-and-retrieve-its-content)

Comment: Can you please share full html code? may be it's inside some frame

Comment: Little update: I have successfully managed to get into my iframe thanks to "driver.switch_to_frame(3)". But I had to count manually the number of iframe... which is not very convenient.
Turcia, I applied your method but the result is the same.

Comment: @AnkurSingh: I have checked, it isn't inside other frame

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the `HTML` you have shared the value of the `id` attribute i.e. **`DWT54`** looks dynamic to me. So we have to construct a dynamic `css` or `xpath` to identify the `frame` and instead of `driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_id(frame_reference))` we have to use **`driver.switch_to.frame(frame_reference)`** as follows:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'_content_ifr') and contains(@title,'Texte richeFaites')]"))
```